# Is it correct to use both verb-to-be and verb-to-have in an interrogative sentence?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement, interrogatives

> Is the man you met good-looking and have a stable job?

> Is it vegan and have high protein?

Answer (score 3):

You can only do this if the root verb (the first *do*, *is*, *have*, or modal) is the same for both.  If it isn't, you have to "start over".

> Did he walk to the park and find the playground?

> Is he walking to the park and did he find the playground?

> Is he walking to the park and looking for his cousin?

Also note that at least in AmE, possessive *have* always requires *do* in questions.

> Is it vegan and does it have high protein?

*Has*/*have*/*had* as part of a perfect verb construction can take the place of *do* or *is* and that **does not** take a *do*/*does*/*did*.